# Get list of attribute decorators in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
class Test {
    @First()
    @Second()
    public someAttribute;
}

var t = new Test();
var decorators = t.getListOfAttributeDecorators("someAttribute");
console.log(decorators); // [First, Second]
```

I would like to implement the "getListOfAttributeDecorators" function, but dont know how. Or is there any other way to get the list of attribute decorators?

Answer (score 13):

You can get data about your custom decorators using [reflect-metadata](https://github.com/rbuckton/reflect-metadata). It's possible by defining metadata of property inside decorator's implementation -
 [see on codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/8llovm3mpj?autoresize=1&expanddevtools=1&fontsize=12&hidenavigation=1&moduleview=1). You can do it only with your custom decorators however third-party libs often also use such approach with a different `metadata key`

```
// be sure to import reflect-metadata
// without importing reflect-metadata Reflect.defineMetadata and other will not be defined.
import "reflect-metadata";

function First(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
  // define metadata with value "First"
  Reflect.defineMetadata("custom:anotations:first", "First", target, propertyKey);
}

function Second(target: Object, propertyKey: string | symbol) {
  // define metadata with value { second: 2 }
  // be sure that metadata key is different from First
  Reflect.defineMetadata("custom:anotations:second", { second: 2 }, target, propertyKey);
}

class Test {
  @First
  @Second
  someAttribute: string;
}

// get decorators

function getDecorators(target: any, propertyName: string | symbol): string[] {
  // get info about keys that used in current property
  const keys: any[] = Reflect.getMetadataKeys(target, propertyName);
  const decorators = keys
    // filter your custom decorators
    .filter(key => key.toString().startsWith("custom:anotations"))
    .reduce((values, key) => {
      // get metadata value.
      const currValues = Reflect.getMetadata(key, target, propertyName);
      return values.concat(currValues);
    }, []);

  return decorators;
}

// test

var t = new Test();
var decorators = getDecorators(t, "someAttribute"); // output is [{ second: 2}, "First"]
console.log(decorators);
```

Don't forget to add `"emitDecoratorMetadata": true` to your `tsconfig.json` in order to be able to manipulate with metadata.

Bonus: implementation with `class decorators` support - [see on codesandox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/p7oy15rw60?expanddevtools=1&fontsize=12&hidenavigation=1)

P.S. It's the old question, however, I hope my answer will help someone.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to maintain a data structure which holds that information, something like:

```
const REGISTRY = new Map<string, Map<string, string[]>>();
function register(cls: string, property: string, decorator: string) {
    let map: Map<string, string[]>;

    if (REGISTRY.has(cls)) {
        map = REGISTRY.get(cls);
    } else {
        map = new Map<string, string[]>();
        REGISTRY.set(cls, map);
    }

    let list: string[];
    if (map.has(property)) {
        list = map.get(property);
    } else {
        list = [];
        map.set(property, list);
    }

    if (list.indexOf(decorator) < 0) {
        list.push(decorator);
    }
}

function First() {
    return function (cls: any, property: string) {
        register(cls.constructor.name, property, "First");
    }
}

function Second() {
    return function (cls: any, property: string) {
        register(cls.constructor.name, property, "Second");
    }
}

class Test {
    @First()
    @Second()
    public someAttribute;

    public getListOfAttributeDecorators(property: string): string[] {
        const name = this.constructor.name;
        return !REGISTRY.has(name) ? [] : REGISTRY.get(name).get(property);
    }
}

let t = new Test();
let names = t.getListOfAttributeDecorators("someAttribute");
console.log(names); // ["Second", "First"]
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=const%20REGISTRY%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20register(cls%3A%20string%2C%20property%3A%20string%2C%20decorator%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20map%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(REGISTRY.has(cls))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20REGISTRY.get(cls)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20REGISTRY.set(cls%2C%20map)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(map.has(property))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20map.get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map.set(property%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(list.indexOf(decorator)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(decorator)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20First()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22First%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22Second%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40First()%0A%20%20%20%20%40Second()%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someAttribute%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getListOfAttributeDecorators(property%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20name%20%3D%20this.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20!REGISTRY.has(name)%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20REGISTRY.get(name).get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20t.getListOfAttributeDecorators(%22someAttribute%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Second%22%2C%20%22First%22%5D#src=const%20REGISTRY%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3E()%3B%0Afunction%20register(cls%3A%20string%2C%20property%3A%20string%2C%20decorator%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20map%3A%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(REGISTRY.has(cls))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20REGISTRY.get(cls)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map%3Cstring%2C%20string%5B%5D%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20REGISTRY.set(cls%2C%20map)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20let%20list%3A%20string%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(map.has(property))%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20map.get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20map.set(property%2C%20list)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(list.indexOf(decorator)%20%3C%200)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20list.push(decorator)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20First()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22First%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20Second()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20function%20(cls%3A%20any%2C%20property%3A%20string)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20register(cls.constructor.name%2C%20property%2C%20%22Second%22)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Test%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%40First()%0A%20%20%20%20%40Second()%0A%20%20%20%20public%20someAttribute%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getListOfAttributeDecorators(property%3A%20string)%3A%20string%5B%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20const%20name%20%3D%20this.constructor.name%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20!REGISTRY.has(name)%20%3F%20%5B%5D%20%3A%20REGISTRY.get(name).get(property)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20t%20%3D%20new%20Test()%3B%0Alet%20names%20%3D%20t.getListOfAttributeDecorators(%22someAttribute%22)%3B%0Aconsole.log(names)%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%22Second%22%2C%20%22First%22%5D))